# Can a local Git repository have a different folder name than the version stored on Github?

Tags: git, github

When using Git is it possible to use a different folder name on desktop than the project name on Github?

For example is there a way to accomplish this?

**Github:** `/codeWars-someTest`

**Desktop:** `/someTest`

In my case on the desktop the repo will already exist in a codeWars folder.
`/codeWars/sometest`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the root folder name has nothing to do with the GitHub repository name

```
cd /codeWars/sometest
git remote add origin https://github.com/<you>/codeWars-someTest
```

From there, you can add/commit and push: that will go into the GitHub `codeWars-someTest` repository.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, a repository does not have to be named the same, so far as the code in local machine has a git initialize in it.  Then you mirror the folder in the local with the one in the GitHub repository.